# why jquery-ui autocomplete list does not show on large list

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

On smaller list of options the autocomplete drop down list does show on focus. but if the options are more than a specific number (50 to be exact) it no longer shows.

How to make it show no matter what the number of options in the list ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sst;
  //auto complete for artist
  $('#artist').autocomplete({
    source: 'artists.php',
    minLength: 0,
    select: function(a, b) {
      sst = b.item.value;
    }
  }).focus(function() {
    $(this).data("uiAutocomplete").search($(this).val());
  });
  //auto complete for title
  $('#title').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "titles.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          q1: sst,
          q2: request.term
        },
        success: function(data) {
          response(data);
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 0
  }).on('focus', function(event) {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
  });
});
```

the mysql query :

```
      <?php 
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','1313');
if(!$db){
        die( "connection failed  ");
}
$db_s = mysql_select_db("LYRICSFINDER",$db);
$data = array();
$searchTerm1 = trim(strip_tags($_GET["q1"]));
$searchTerm1 = addslashes($searchTerm1); 
$searchTerm2 = trim(strip_tags($_GET["q2"]));
$searchTerm2 = addslashes($searchTerm2);      
$query = "SELECT TITLE FROM DATA WHERE ARTIST LIKE '%".$searchTerm1."%' AND TITLE  LIKE '%".$searchTerm2."%' ORDER BY TITLE ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query,$db);
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){
    $data[] = $row['TITLE'];
    $i++;
    if($i>50)break;
}
mysql_close($db);
echo json_encode($data);
  ?>
```

Comment: Can you paste mysql query

Comment: without that condition on the result, the list doesn't appear unless i tape some character. but that's not the behavior i'm after

Comment: @NeoMosaid but that's what it is supposed to do: To show once you start typing.

Comment: the minLength:0 part makes it show even if you type 0 character, but on focus. if you want i can add an image screenshot , its working, but with 50 results only